# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement') Angular

Tags: angular, viewchild

I'm trying to make the `chatMessages` container to scroll to bottom when its loaded, when the scroll to bottom button is clicked and also when a new message is send. But i keep getting this error and nothing works. Below is the log I get :

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')
    at chatroom.component.ts:65:27
    at timer (zone.js:2367:41)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:402:31)
    at core.mjs:25998:55
    at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25998:36)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401:60)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:26308:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401:60)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:173:47)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:483:34)
```

Ok this is what I did : Chatroom.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, Output, HostListener, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { PickerComponent } from '@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart';
import { User, Message } from 'src/user';
import { ChatService } from 'src/app/services/chat.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-chatroom',
  templateUrl: './chatroom.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chatroom.component.css'],
})
export class ChatroomComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('chatMessages') chatMessages!: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
  @Input() selectedContact: User | null = null;
  @Output() goBackClicked = new EventEmitter<void>();

  message: string = '';
  showEmojiPicker: boolean = false;
  isMobile: boolean;
  showScrollToBottomButton: boolean = false;

  constructor(private chatService: ChatService) {
    this.isMobile = window.innerWidth < 992;
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.scrollToBottom();
  }
  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event: any) {
    this.isMobile = event.target.innerWidth < 992;
  }
  goBack() {
    this.goBackClicked.emit();
  }

  sendMessage() {
    if (this.message.trim() === '') return;

    const newMessage: Message = {
      content: this.message,
      sentByUser: true,
      timestamp: new Date(),
    };

    if (this.selectedContact) {
      this.selectedContact.messages.push(newMessage);
    }

    this.message = '';
    this.scrollToBottom();
  }
  scrollToBottom() {
    try {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.chatMessages.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.chatMessages.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
      }, 0);
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
}
```

Then in the html file :

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100 px-0 mx-0">
  <div class="chat-container d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="header d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between px-4 py-2" style="position: sticky; top: 0;" *ngIf="selectedContact">
      <div class="contact_details row align-items-center">
        <!-- Back button -->
        <div class="col-auto" *ngIf="selectedContact && isMobile">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="goBack()">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="contact_image col-auto">
          <img [src]="selectedContact.profileImage" alt="" class="rounded-circle" width="40">
        </div>
        <div class="contact_name col-auto">{{ selectedContact.name }}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col video_call">
          <a href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-video"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col audio_call">
          <a href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-phone"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col menu">
          <a href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis-vertical fs-5"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-messages pb-3" id="chatMessages">
      <div *ngIf="!selectedContact || !selectedContact.messages.length" class="w-100 h-100 text-center d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <h3>{{ selectedContact ? 'No messages yet!' : 'Select a contact to start a conversation!' }}</h3>
      </div>
      <div *ngFor="let message of selectedContact?.messages">
        <div class="message-cont">
          <div class="{{message.sentByUser ? 'sent' : 'received'}}">
            <div class="message {{message.sentByUser ? 'sent' : 'received'}}">{{message.content}}</div>
            <div class="msg_time">{{message.timestamp | date: 'h:mm a'}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button *ngIf="selectedContact" class="scroll-to-bottom" (click)="scrollToBottom()">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down"></i>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="chat-input" *ngIf="selectedContact">
      <button class="btn px-2" (click)="toggleEmojiPicker()">
        <i class="fa-regular fa-face-smile text-primary fs-5"></i>
      </button>
      <input
        [(ngModel)]="message"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Type a message..."
        #msg
      />
      <button class="send btn btn-primary" (click)="sendMessage()">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-paper-plane"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
    <emoji-mart
      *ngIf="showEmojiPicker"
      (emojiSelect)="addEmoji($event)"
      [isNative]="true"
      [showPreview]="false"
      [perLine]="8"
      [emojiSize]="18"
    ></emoji-mart>
  </div>
</div>
```

The chat messages has messages and it should scroll to the bottom that's to the last message when its loaded, the scroll to bottom is clicked or a new message sent but none of this happens. Please help!

Comment: You are missing the ```#chatMessages``` reference into your template. https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables